# open and find a string in word document using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am able to open the word document using c# but i also want it to open on page where my string matches.

```
protected void New_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
        app.Visible = true;
        object visible = true;
        object filepath = @"D:\Files\Process\TestingDocument-Latest1.docx";
        object optional = System.Type.Missing;

        Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref filepath, ref optional, ref
            optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref
            optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional, ref optional);


        object findText = "\"Quotation Day\" means";
        int docc = doc.Paragraphs.Count;
        Word.Range rng = doc.Paragraphs[docc].Range;
        rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
        rng.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                        Type.Missing, Type.Missing);




    }
```

let me know if any additional info required .

Comment: What's the issue? Have you got any errors?

Comment: You tagged this as ASP.NET, but you're using Office Interop libraries. This is a very bad idea. Microsoft says [don't do it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). Instead, use a library that knows how to manipulate Word documents, such as [DocX](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/DocX).

Comment: no, i am not getting any error message, it just simply doesn't go the location.